# IE add on Edge IE mode

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have enabled Enterprise mode and redirected all the intranet site to open on IE.
Problem is that I have IE add-ons which only open in IE is not opening in Edge IE mode. When I am trying to open the internal page it's given me jar file extension and asking me to choose the application through which I can open the jar file. In IE I am not facing the issue.
Is there any settings I need to do for IE ADD-on to open in IE mode

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your add on? Is it BHO or some ActiveX? Also, inform us which steps you have follow to open your IE add on using Edge IE mode? Let us know which version of the MS Edge browser you are using making this test? It can help us to test the issue on our end.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT It is hyperian plugin which runs perfectly on standalone IE 11. But when trying to open in edge rendering IE it tried to open a jar file to install the plug in but plugin is already installed in IE

Comment: @pikas It's just a warning, if you click allow, does the addon runs correctly?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT no it will try open microsoft app store. Strange thing is that Same IE version which runs perfectly on windows 7 doesn't behave same way in windows 10